# Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, cms

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in Z:\home\tehnogroup\www\core\model\modx\modmanagerresponse.class.php on line 41`

В админке вот такая вот ошибка, что делать?

Comment: У меня антологичная штука. как решили проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вроде все написано...

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function get()`

где-то что-то не добавлено.

А возможно, что и версия php старая :)